# notification-daemon icon

Tags: openbox, theme, icons, notifications

I am trying to change the icon of notification-daemon,
working on Debian with Openbox, with tint2 as panel, all icons are from Numix theme (I have changed in .gtkrc-2.0 and gtk-3.0/settings.ini that I want to use that theme).

But when I get notifications from something (notify-send for example) I get this icon: [image]

I have tried searching for it but I don't find it, any idea where is it stored? Or how I can change the behavior of notification-daemon to change it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My fault, in the file /usr/share/icon/theme/index.theme I was missing part of the directories that theme had, so I was looking for the gnome theme (which was inherit by the theme) and I did not see that icon, so, changed the list of directories and done, I put them all the folders and it looked like:

```
# Directory list
Directories=8x8/emblems,16x16/actions,16x16/animations,16x16/apps,16x16/categories,16x16/devices,16x16/emblems,16x16/emotes,16x16/mimetypes,16x16/places,16x16/status,22x22/actions,22x22/animations,22x22/apps,22x22/categories,22x22/devices,22x22/emblems,22x22/emotes,22x22/mimetypes,22x22/places,22x22/status,24x24/actions,24x24/apps,24x24/categories,24x24/devices,24x24/emblems,24x24/emotes,24x24/mimetypes,24x24/places,24x24/status,32x32/actions,32x32/animations,32x32/apps,32x32/categories,32x32/devices,32x32/emblems,32x32/emotes,32x32/mimetypes,32x32/places,32x32/status,48x48/actions,48x48/animations,48x48/apps,48x48/categories,48x48/devices,48x48/emblems,48x48/emotes,48x48/mimetypes,48x48/places,48x48/status,256x256/actions,256x256/apps,256x256/categories,256x256/devices,256x256/emblems,256x256/emotes,256x256/mimetypes,256x256/places,256x256/status,scalable/actions,scalable/apps,scalable/devices,scalable/emblems,scalable/mimetypes,scalable/places,scalable/status,scalable/categories
```